# How to test multiple maven projects using single command?

Tags: maven, testing

I've got a set of maven projects and I feel really tired to test every project with `mvn test`. How can I organize my code to run all the tests using just one command? Can I do this using `<modules>`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly what `<modules>` is for. So if you run `mvn clean test` in the root dir of your super-project the `clean` and `test` phases are going to be executed against the 1st module and then against the 2nd and so on.

If there are dependencies between modules, then Maven will build a graph and will know the right order of modules to work with.

If you still need to execute a command against only one or two modules you can do that in the super-project dir with `-pl module1-name,module2-name` flag.